# how do I find all Elements of a Group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, problem-solving

I am given a Group $\mathbb{Z_{11}^*}$. a multiplicative group.

How do i find all elements of this Group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $\mathbb Z_{n}^*$ are the invertible elements of the ring $(\mathbb Z_{n},+,\times)$ and it's simple to show that $$\overline k\in \mathbb Z_{n}^*\iff \gcd(k,n)=1$$

In your example $11$ is a prime hence the ring $(\mathbb Z_{11},+,\times)$ is a field so all its elements but $0$ are invertible.

Comment: Typo : the ring is $\mathbb Z_{11}$ not $\mathbb Z$.